# The if/else statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement

I want to show a suitable button with if/else statement. For example, when none of the checkboxes are checked I want to display the disabled button, but when one or more checkboxes are checked I want to display another button.

Js

```
 $("#checkAll").change(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
```

Html

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" style="margin-left:-10px" />
 <input type="checkbox"  style="margin-left:5px" />
 <input type="checkbox"  style="margin-left:5px" />


<div class="ml-2">
               if(checked){
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ">Delete</button>
               }else{
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" disabled>Delete</button>
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: Include both buttons in the html (without the `if(checked)`) with one hidden - then in your js show/hide them as appropriate

Comment: Are there separate buttons or the same one having it's `disabled` state changed? Would a single button work for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When none of the checkboxes are checked I want to display the disabled button, but when 1 or more checkbox are checked I want to display another button.

You can include both buttons in the html with one hidden - then in your js show/hide them as appropriate.

A basic implementation would to check:

```
if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
```

then use `.show()` `.hide()` on each of the buttons as required.

This can be made more streamlined, eg using `.toggle($("input:checkbox:checked").length == 0)` but this is to show the explicit if/else as requested in the title.

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$("input:checkbox").change(function() { 
  if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
    $(".ml-2>.btn-danger").hide();
    $(".ml-2>.btn-outline-danger").show();
  } else {
    $(".ml-2>.btn-outline-danger").hide();
    $(".ml-2>.btn-danger").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />


<div class="ml-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " style='display:none;' >Delete</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" disabled>Delete (disabled)</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

As long the button is right next to the other button you don't even need no javascript for that.
Thats of course quite a simple approach and can easily be 'hacked' via the Inspector. But if you do it with Javascript it can be hacked as well.

```css
.checkbox + .button {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.checkbox:checked + .button {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox + .button + .button2 {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:checked + .button + .button2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<div class="button">Button 1</div>
<div class="button2">Button 2</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I am aiming for the disabled button has to be shown, and then when the input is checked another button should be shown instead of disabled

Comment: This is a neat, non-javascript solution - just needs expanding for OPs specific scenario

Comment: I just added some code to make it fit your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If - as outlined - you want to have two buttons (rather than, say, one button where you change the classes and properties) you can:

1. listen for when one of the `checkboxes` changes
2. then check the collective state of all the `checkboxes`
3. then, depending on that collective state, apply:

- `Element.classList.add('show')`
- `Element.classList.remove('show')`

to show and hide the respective buttons.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
// DECLARE VARIABLES
const btnDanger = document.querySelector('.btn-danger');
const btnOutlineDanger = document.querySelector('.btn-outline-danger');
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');


// FUNCTION: REVIEW CHECKBOXES
const reviewCheckBoxes = () => {

  let allUnchecked = true;
  
  checkBoxes.forEach((checkBox) => {

    if (checkBox.checked) {

      allUnchecked = false;
    }
  });
  
  if (allUnchecked === true) {
  
    btnDanger.classList.remove('show');
    btnOutlineDanger.classList.add('show');
  }
  
  else if (allUnchecked === false) {

    btnDanger.classList.add('show');
    btnOutlineDanger.classList.remove('show');
  }
}


// ADD EVENT LISTENERS TO EACH OF THE CHECKBOXES
checkBoxes.forEach((checkBox) => {

  checkBox.addEventListener('change', reviewCheckBoxes);

});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.btn-danger,
.btn-outline-danger,
input[type="checkbox"]#checkAll {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.btn-danger,
.btn-outline-danger {
  display: none;
}

.btn-danger.show,
.btn-outline-danger.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ">Delete</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger show" disabled>Delete</button>
```